# jQuery Validate - cannot submit form successfully more than once

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, jquery-validate

I am trying to redo my Email Contact form using the jQuery Validate Plugin and AJAX inside the `submitHandler`. I found that it works, however, it only works once. After I try to resubmit the form, I no longer receive the emails. I would need to manually refresh the page in order for the form to resubmit successfully. Anyone know the issue?

Here's my code:

```
<form class="form ajax" id="contact_form" method="post" action="php/contact.php">

    <div id="response" class="response">
        <h2>Thank You! Your message has been sent.</h2>
    </div>

    <p class="name">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" autocomplete="off" />
    </p>
    <p class="email">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="mail@example.com" autocomplete="off" />
    </p>
    <p class="subject">
        <label for="subject">Subject</label>
        <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Your Subject" autocomplete="off" />
    </p>
    <p class="message">
        <label for="message">Message</label>
        <textarea name="message" placeholder="Your Message" id="message"></textarea>
    </p>
    <p class="submit">
        <input class="submit-button" type="submit" id="submit" value="Send" />
    </p>
</form>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$.validator.setDefaults({
    errorClass: 'form_error',
    errorElement: 'div'
})

$("#contact_form").validate({
    rules: {
        name: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 2
        },
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        subject: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 2
        },
        message: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 10
        }
    },
    messages: {
        name: {
            required: "Please enter your name",
            minlength: "Your name seems a bit short doesn't it?"
        },
        email: {
            required: "Please enter your email address",
            email: "Please enter a valid email address"
        },
        subject: {
            required: "Please enter a subject",
            minlength: "Your subject seems a bit short doesn't it?"
        },
        message: {
            required: "Please enter your message",
            minlength: "Your message should be at least 10 characters"
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        var that = $(form),
        url = that.attr('action'),
        type = that.attr('method'),
        data = {};

        that.find('[name]').each(function(index, value) {
            var that = $(this),
                name = that.attr('name'),
                value = that.val();

            data[name] = value;
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: type,
            data: data,
            success: function(response) {
                $('#name').val('');
                $('#email').val('');
                $('#subject').val('');
                $('#message').val('');
                $('#response').fadeIn(300, function () {
                    $('#response').delay(5000).fadeOut(300);
                });
            }
        });

        return false;   
    }
});
```

Comment: Show the ***complete*** code.  Where is the rest of the `.validate()` method?  Where is the HTML for this form?

Comment: Read:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Your latest revision is missing the closing brackets, `});`, for the DOM ready event handler.

Comment: Your problem seems to be within your `ajax()` success handler and that's going to be up to you to troubleshoot against your server-side PHP function.  Otherwise, your code is working fine.  As you can see by my jsFiddle, the `submitHandler` will let you submit the form as many times as you wish.  http://jsfiddle.net/zRd8Y/1/

Comment: Sorry about the missing }); i copy pasted the whole thing but it didnt show that last one... I'm not here too often and sometimes the code thing doesnt want to show everything I paste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**  Since posting this answer, the OP updated his question to fully reflect my suggestions.  His code is working properly as far as can be tested:  http://jsfiddle.net/zRd8Y/1/

My original answer follows...

---

You 1have not shown nearly enough code for anyone to say with certainty what's going wrong.  You need to show [a *complete* working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including HTML and the rest of your `.validate()` method.

However, this bit of code is very strange and likely a large factor in your issue:

```
success: function(element) {
    element.remove();   
}
```

How can you do anything with this form when every element is permanently removed from the DOM upon successful validation of each input?

**Quote OP**:

> *"I would need to manually refresh the page in order for the form to resubmit successfully."*

**The only way to restore something removed from the DOM using [the `.remove()` method](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) is to reload the page**.

---

According to [the documentation for the `success` callback](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#success):

> **success**
>   Type: String or Function()
>   If specified, the error label is displayed to show a valid element. If a String is given, it is added as a class to the label. **If a Function is given, it is called with the label (as a jQuery object) and the validated input (as a DOM element). The label can be used to add a text like “ok!”.**

In other words, the `success` callback was meant as a means to display the `label` element on a valid form element, instead of *only* on an invalid element.  Your usage to remove the element from the DOM is not appropriate here.  Since you're removing the input elements, I also do not understand how your form can be sending any data at all, even the first time.

As a start, try eliminating the `success` callback option entirely.

---

**NOTES**:

Your code...

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
    var that = $("#contact_form"),
    url = that.attr('action'),
    ....
```

FYI, the `form` argument is provided to you, and it already represents *your* form.  In other words, `form` represents `$("#contact_form")`.  So you can simply use `$(form)` instead...

```
submitHandler: function(form) {

    url = $(form).attr('action'),
    ....
```

Comment: Hi Sparky. I didn't think the rest of the Validate code was necessary since it wasn't the problem. The issue is how the submit would not refresh the form after the ajax is run. So what happens is on the first load of the page, the form would be able to send the email. Since I am trying to use the ajax, it wont refresh but then carry out the animation of the success message. Then when I try to send another email by filling up the form, I receive nothing. I added the rest of the validate code for u if u think it will help.

Comment: @bsebastian86, The `submitHandler` is a callback function that fires off when the form is valid... that is all.  The `submitHandler` has nothing to do with preventing the form from submitting a second time.

Comment: @bsebastian86, I just noticed that you changed your code to reflect my answer.

Comment: @bsebastian86, [showing enough code to make a complete working example is a requirement at SO](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), no matter if you think it's relevant to the problem.  1)  It's helpful to future readers. 2) It's helpful to people trying to answer so they don't have to re-construct a demo from scratch. 3) Sometimes, the problem is not where you think, caused by broken HTML markup, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Sparky. I think you've helped greatly. I may have to look into the server side for this one. Thanks a lot. Closing this.